# Expo firebase facebook log Error: auth/invalid-credential

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, facebook-login

I'm building an expo react-native app and trying to add a Facebook login method.

I have created an app in developers.facebook.com and added IOS, Android platforms as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUISH.png)

In firebase, I have enabled Facebook auth and added APP ID and APP secret.
Copied the OAuth redirect URI to my Facebook app config

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv253.png)

- should facebook login be green ?

then in my code I did the following:

```
async function loginWithFacebook() {
    try {
        await Facebook.initializeAsync({
            appId: '3433583816677371',
          });
        const {type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({permissions: ['public_profile'],});
        if (type === 'success') {
            console.log('user has suuccceeeded his login ');
            console.log('type and token', type, token)
          const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);
          Alert.alert('Logged in!', `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`);
            const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token)
            // Sign-in the user with the credential
            console.log('cred', facebookCredential)
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential).catch(error => {
                console.log('error siginig innnnn', error.code);
            });
        } else {
          console.log('user has cancelled his login ');
        }
      } catch ({ message }) {
        console.log('user has cancelled his login ', message);
        }
}
```

I get all credentials and so, but it fails in firebase.auth().signInWithCredntial(...) witht he following error:

- auth/invalid-credential

I followed the documentation however I don't know why it's failing !!

Any help, please ??